# Not able to single-step into INT or CLI instructions in QEMU

Tags: visual-studio-code, assembly, x86, gdb, qemu

I am using x86 and x86_64 Assembly extension from VSCode to debug, I am not able to step in few assembly instructions:

int, cli

But when I type F5, the program works well. So, the program not struck on them.

Other assembly works well.

I expect I am able to step in each assembly instruction, so I am able to double-check all registers.

Comment: I assume you're writing a freestanding program or OS, inside QEMU acting as a GDB remote?  `cli` is privileged so you can't normally execute it in a user-space process (unless you've called `iopl()` on Linux to set your process's IO privilege level to 0.)

Comment: Are you programming code for 16-bit real mode and calling BIOS interrupts? Or is this for your own OS?

Comment: I am writing a real-mode 16bit bootloader. QEMU acting as a GDB remote. Also, not step out or step over. I don't know if there is a workaround to step over the privileged instruction.

Comment: Real mode doesn't have any concept of "privileged" instructions.  The important point is that they deal with interrupts.  I assume there's no problem single-stepping other instructions like `wbinvd` or `lidt` that are privileged in protected mode?

Comment: Related: [Bios Firmware - How to step through software interrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/134279011) - ECM's debugger can single-step into `int` software interrupt instructions.  As for `cli`, IDK, I'm not sure if that stops TF from working.  You might want to use Bochs' built-in debugger which is designed for osdev stuff.